# Getting An Interstitial Ad Error When Ad Not Ready - Swift

Tags: swift, interstitial, google-mobile-ads

I currently have an interstitial ad running for my viewcontroller. The issue is that when the ad is not ready, my app crashes with the error. If someone could help me with the following problems, I would appreciate it heaps! Thank you

View Controller : Issue being when the ad is not ready, app crashes with the error.

```
class JournalViewController: UIViewController, GADFullScreenContentDelegate {
    
    var interstitial: GADInterstitialAd!   
 
    override func viewDidLoad() {

        super.viewDidLoad()

        let request = GADRequest()
        GADInterstitialAd.load(withAdUnitID:"id ...",
                                      request: request,
                            completionHandler: { [self] ad, error in
                              if let error = error {
                                print("Failed to load interstitial ad with error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
                                return
                              }
                                interstitial = ad
                                interstitial?.fullScreenContentDelegate = self
                            }
          )
                
       let randomTime = Double(arc4random() + 20).truncatingRemainder(dividingBy: 60.0)
        Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: randomTime, target: self, selector: #selector(ViewController.CreateAd), userInfo: nil, repeats: false)
        
    }
    @objc func CreateAd() -> GADInterstitialAd {
        
        if interstitial != nil {
                    interstitial.present(fromRootViewController: self)
                    let randomTime = Double(arc4random() + 20).truncatingRemainder(dividingBy: 60.0)
                    Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: randomTime, target: self, selector: #selector(ViewController.CreateAd), userInfo: nil, repeats: false)
        } else {
            print("Ad not ready") // Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=2, address=0x7ffee788bff8)
            interstitial = CreateAd()
        }
        return interstitial
            }
```

Furthermore, if someone has time to also look at this. I want to have the ad run multiple times. I understand interstitial ads do not allow this and to combat this I implemented this function but it does not work. Is this incorrect?

```
    func adDidDismissFullScreenContent(_ ad: GADFullScreenPresentingAd) {
        
        interstitial = CreateAd()
        
    }
```

Comment: Why are you setting `interstitial = CreateAd()` inside `CreateAd`?

Comment: My reasoning for this is, if the ad is not ready, it will run a loop till the ad is ready for it to present again. This might not be correct or make sense, but it's just my thought process

Comment: You're calling `CreateAd()` 1) from inside `adDidDismissFullScreenContent(_:)`, 2) from inside `viewDidLoad`, and 3) from inside `CreateAd()` itself. That can't be right. You're probably causing infinite recursion, making it crash.

Comment: In terms of adDidDismissFullScreenContent, the purpose of this is just so the interstitial ad can repeat once it's closed. I'll have a look at how i can improve this, at least I know now that these are the issues. Thank you for that

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't return the ad from `CreateAd()`, the ad should be set when the completionHandler of `GADInterstitialAd.load(..)` is called.

This should be your createAd function (without returning anything):

```
var interstitial: GADInterstitialAd?


func createAd() {
    GADInterstitialAd.load(withAdUnitID:"id ...",
                                  request: GADRequest(),
                        completionHandler: { ad, error in
                          if let error = error {
                            print("Failed to load interstitial ad with error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
                            return
                          }
                            interstitial = ad
                            interstitial?.fullScreenContentDelegate = self
                        }
      )
}
```

then present it whenever you like, and call `createAd()` again after ad dismiss